# jquery loop through different backgrounds

Tags: jquery, loops, background

I'm trying to change different backgrounds for a div looping through an array of images and timing it every 5 sec.

here's my code:

```
function changeBG(){

     //array of backgrounds
     var array = ["test.jpg", "test2.jpg", "test3.jpg",];


     for ( var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; ++i){
         $('.round-mask').css('background-image', 'url("images/work/'+array[i]+'")');

      }

}

window.setInterval(changeBG(), 5000);
```

This is not working, I can see it is looping, but I'm getting always the 3rd image.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Mauro

Comment: The for loop loops though the array, and replaces the background image with the new one on every turn, making the last image always appear.

Comment: don't use %3, please use %array.length, thanks, it's my bad :)

Comment: Watch out how you are calling `setInterval` you should be passing it a reference to the function, a callback. At present if you pass it `changeBG()` it will simply run the function when you pass it only. If you pass it as a callback `changeBG` it will run the function at each interval. [See the difference here](http://jsfiddle.net/hAxHt/1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Please Try~

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
    var now = 0;
    var int = self.setInterval("changeBG()", 1000);
    var array = ["001.jpg", "002.jpg", "003.jpg", ];

    function changeBG(){
        //array of backgrounds
        now = (now+1) % array.length ;
        $('.round-mask').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');
    }
</script>
```

and forget about this~

```
 for ( var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
 $('.round-mask').css('background-image', 'url("images/work/'+array[i]+'")');

  }
```

Comment: the does fix the for loop issue but not the overall problem

Comment: that will make value of now be "0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,..." :)

Comment: and what happens when there are more than 3 items in the array ?

Comment: again no its not it doesn't count for length of array ! i gave you the right answer along time ago

Comment: @mcgrailm: haha~ you are right, It's my bad, we should use array.length

Comment: I want previous and nest function. How to do that

Comment: @G Naga Subrahmanyam : 
now -= 1  for previous and 
now +=1  for next, then using this code: 
$('.round-mask').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work:

```
var i = 0;

function changeBG(){

     //array of backgrounds
     var array = ["test.jpg", "test2.jpg", "test3.jpg",];



    $('.round-mask').css('background-image', 'url("images/work/'+array[i]+'")');

    if(i == array.length -1){
         i= 0;
    }
    else{
        i++;
    }


}
```

Comment: this will break if you have more than three items in your array

Comment: You should change `if (i==2)` to `if(i==array.length)` so otherwise if you have more images in the array than 3 it would only show the first 3.

Comment: @scoobler no, actually, it should be array.length -1.  array.length will fail.  b/c array indexes are zero based.

Comment: Just thought, it should actually be `if(i==(array.length-1))` with it being a zero based index on the array. PS +1 for being very close.

Comment: if we wanted to get really technical, we should put array.length -1 into a variable and use that,  so it doesn't have to look it up on every itteration

Answer (score 0):

This really worked. 2014.

```
var i =0 ;

//array of backgrounds
var array = [
    "1.jpg", 
    "2.jpg", 
    "3.jpg", 
    "4.jpg", 
    "5.jpg", 
    "6.jpg", 
    "7.jpg", 
    ];

function changeBG(){
    if ( i > array.length -1) {
        i = 0;
    }

    $('.slideContainer').css('background-image', 'url("img/backgrounds/'+array[i]+'")');
    i++;
}

window.setInterval("changeBG()", 5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this out

```
var i =0 ;

//array of backgrounds
var array = ["test.jpg", "test2.jpg", "test3.jpg"];

function changeBG(){
    if ( i > array.length -1) {
        i = 0;
    }

    $('.round-mask').css('background-image', 'url("images/work/'+array[i]+'")');
    i++;
}

window.setInterval(changeBG(), 5000);
```

Comment: It kind of works, but it loops 4 times instead of 3 and the 4th time returns 'undefined'

Comment: @Mauro74 make sure you take out the trailing comma in the array; @Patricia thanks !

Comment: @Mauro74 did you make sure you don't have trailing comma in your array ?

Comment: yea, this is going to break to.

Comment: b/c array.length is 3.  so if i = 3, it'll try to get the 4th element, b/c array are 0 indexed.  so, you need to check for array.length -1 :)

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> $(element).on("click",function(){
>   $("<div>").css("background-image", "url("+array[(i-1)]+")");
> if (i == array.length){
>  i=1;
> }
> else {
>  i++;
> }
> })
> ```

This is my edit, so actually it run
Or

> ```
> $(element).css("background-image", "url("+array[(i-1)]+")");
> i == bb.length ? i=1 : i++;
> ```