# setInterval to change background from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Hello this is based very closely on:

[jquery loop through different backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977837/jquery-loop-through-different-backgrounds)

This solution did work for me, however I do not want the background's to change on document ready - they should be triggered by a function. For some reason this makes the backgrounds change too fast, they flicker 3 at once so it looks like the loop is over running somewhere:

```
function run()
{
// Set multicolour backgrounds
window.setInterval( multicolour(), 3000);
}

var colour = 0;
var colours = Array('', 'pink', 'red', 'green', 'light');

function multicolour()
{
    colour = (colour+1) % colours.length ;
    $('body').attr('id', colours[colour]);
    console.log(colour);
}
```

FYI the console log shows the colour flickering 3 times every 3 seconds instead of changing once every 3 seconds. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursive `setTimeout` and use a common timer variable that would be overwritten by unintentional code overwrites.

```
window._timers = {
  changeBackground : null
};

var colour = 0;
var colours = Array('', 'pink', 'red', 'green', 'light');

function multicolour()
{
    colour = (colour+1) % colours.length ;
    $('body').attr('id', colours[colour]);

    // Set multicolour backgrounds
    clearTimeout(window._timers.changeBackground);
    window._timers.changeBackground = setTimeout(multicolour, 3000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FgkWx/

Answer (score 2):

Couple of syntax issues.  You need to pass a `function reference` to `window.setInterval`

I also cleaned up your array declaration.  I don't have jQuery so I didn't attempt to run this code though.

```
function run()
{
  // Set multicolour backgrounds
  window.setInterval( multicolour, 3000);
}

var colour = 0;
var colours = ['', 'pink', 'red', 'green', 'light'];

function multicolour()
{
  colour = (colour+1) % colours.length ;
  $('body').attr('id', colours[colour]);
  console.log(colour);
}
```

Hm.... trying this one that doesn't pollute the global space:
This uses some more advanced Javascript methods, but this way 'colour' and 'colours' don't leak into the global space and pollute things.

```
var changeBackground = (function() {

  var colour = 0;
  var colours = ['', 'pink', 'red', 'green', 'light'];

  return function() {
    colour = (colour+1) % colours.length ;
    document.body.id =  colours[colour];
    console.log(colour);

  };

}());

window.setInterval( changeBackground, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks although the problem still remains, it flickers through colours every 3 seconds instead of just changing to the next colour

Comment: I'd have to see the rest of your code... I don't know where/how `run` is called, for instance.  Do you have a public page or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your original question's answer had a (correct) recursive call you were missing:

```
setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000); // called from changeBackground()
```

Your example here does NOT have `multicolour()` calling itself recursively using setTimeout

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong URL - it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977837/jquery-loop-through-different-backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the callback function in the setInterval declaration:

```
window.setInterval( multicolour(), 3000);
```

Try this:

```
window.setInterval( multicolour, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work like this:

```
var colour = 0;
var colours = Array('', 'pink', 'red', 'green', 'light');

function multicolour(){
    colour = (colour+1) % colours.length ;
    $('body').attr('id', colours[colour]);
    console.log(colour);
}

setInterval( multicolour, 3000);
```

You need to pass a function reference to the setInterval function, not the function's return value.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJLEF/)